# Add a new field that subtracts the quantities of a subquery through the results of a table mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I would like to be able to create a new column in a subquery that subtracts an amount from a given id that comes from a query from another table, which can return several records.

This is the subquery:

```
+---------------------------------------+------------+----------+
| name                                  | id_product | quantity |
+---------------------------------------+------------+----------+
| Samsung Galaxy J3 2017                |         12 |        0 |
| Samsung Galaxy S8                     |         15 |        2 |
| Samsung Galaxy S7                     |         17 |        0 |
| Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge                |         18 |        5 |
| Samsung Galaxy J1 mini Prime Dual SIM |         20 |        1 |
+---------------------------------------+------------+----------+

SELECT pl.name, pl.id_product, psa.quantity as stock 
FROM `ps_product_lang` pl 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product` p ON pl.id_product = p.id_product
LEFT JOIN `ps_category_product` pc ON p.id_product = pc.id_product
LEFT JOIN `ps_stock_available` psa ON p.id_product = psa.id_product
WHERE pc.id_category = 13 AND p.id_category_default = 17 AND p.condition = 'new'
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

The other query could show one or more records:

Other table

```
+------------+-------+
| id_product | total |
+------------+-------+
|         15 |     1 |
|         18 |     2 |
+------------+-------+
SELECT id_product, count(id_product) as total  
FROM ventacompra_tmp 
GROUP BY id_product;
```

The result that I want would be something like that, subtract only the fields whose result comes from the other table and the other fields remain the same, frame with "" fields that change.

```
+---------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------+
| name                                  | id_product | quantity | stock |
+---------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------+
| Samsung Galaxy J3 2017                |         12 |        0 |     0 |
| Samsung Galaxy S8                     |         15 |        2 |   "1" |
| Samsung Galaxy S7                     |         17 |        0 |     0 |
| Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge                |         18 |        5 |   "3" |
| Samsung Galaxy J1 mini Prime Dual SIM |         20 |        1 |     1 |
+---------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, simply do a `LEFT JOIN` on the two different results sets (**derived tables**) using `id_product`.

Now subtract `stock` if the value from the left table is **not NULL**. Use the following:

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       t1.id_product, 
       t1.stock AS quantity,  
       (t1.stock - IFNULL(t2.total, 0)) AS stock 
FROM 
( SELECT pl.name, pl.id_product, psa.quantity as stock 
  FROM `ps_product_lang` pl 
  LEFT JOIN `ps_product` p ON pl.id_product = p.id_product
  LEFT JOIN `ps_category_product` pc ON p.id_product = pc.id_product
  LEFT JOIN `ps_stock_available` psa ON p.id_product = psa.id_product
  WHERE pc.id_category = 13 AND p.id_category_default = 17 AND p.condition = 'new'
  GROUP BY p.id_product ) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT id_product, count(id_product) as total  
    FROM ventacompra_tmp 
    GROUP BY id_product ) AS t2 ON t2.id_product = t1.id_product
```

Comment: Perfect Madhur Bhaiya, only I have change t2.stock by t2.total.
I thank you very much for your help.
How do I give you points?

Comment: Awesome @Madhur, this world needs more people like you, excellent work :)